# Is there a way to control reverberation size with ConvolverNode in WebAudio API?

Tags: signal-processing, web-audio-api

As much as I can see, all of the properties of the reverberation effect come down to the recorded impulse that you use.

Is it possible to control properties such as reverb size or decay using the same recorded impulse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really - though you can apply an envelope on to a long impulse to reduce the decay.  You can artificially generate reasonable-sounding reverbs, too, with envelopes applied to random noise.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. That's a very interesting idea.